# Placing and order via API and payment processing

Tags: orders, api, payment, soap, ce-1.9.0.1

I'd like to create and place an order in Magento using API. I see that exists the method cart.create but I cannot understand what is the correct flow for using it.

The point I cannot figure out how to handle is the payment.

The following use case can work?

1. Create a cart using Magento API
2. Add products to cart using Magento API
3. Set customer, addresses, etc again using Magento API
4. Perform some kind of payment **outside Magento**
5. If payment is successful, call *cart.create*

Thanks

Comment: You can use magento SOAP api to perform this tasks

Answer (score 5):

The full workflow should be like this:

1. Create a shopping cart (`'cart.create'`)
2. Set the customer/guest to the shopping cart (`'cart_customer.set'`)
3. Set customer addresses, for example guest's addresses (`'cart_customer.addresses'`)
4. add/update/remove products to the shopping cart (`'cart_product.add', 'cart_product.update', cart_product.remove'`)
5. get the list of shipping methods (`'cart_shipping.list'`)
6. set shipping method (`'cart_shipping.method'`)
7. get list of payment methods (`'cart_payment.list'`)
8. set payment method (`'cart_payment.method'`)
9. add/remove coupons if necessary (`'cart_coupon.add', 'cart_coupon.remove'`)
10. get total prices (`'cart.totals'`)
11. get information about the shopping cart (`'cart.info'`)
12. get list of licenses (`'cart.licenseAgreement'`)
13. create oder (`'cart.order'`)

There is also a detailed code example for SOAP APIv1 on 
http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/soap/checkout/cart/cart.html